# apache serving the wrong ssl certificate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have the following 2 sections in my httpd.conf file.  I have a wildcard cert installed for *.example.biz installed at the given location.  As you can see the 4 SSL directives are identical (copy and pasted) in both sections.  However, when I go to example.biz I get an ssh error saying the CA certificate expired in 2015.  When I go to the subdomain, I get the right certificate chain that says it expires in 2018.  I apologize that I am using an example, but this is for a client that must remain confidential.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/2017.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/my_biz_2016.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/2017_ca.crt
    <Directory /var/www/MyCompany/example.com/public/>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/example.com/access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MyCompany/example.com/public/
    ServerName example.biz
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/2017.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/my_biz_2016.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/2017_ca.crt
    <Directory /var/www/MyCompany/SubDomain/public/>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/SubDomain/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/SubDomain/access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MyCompany/SubDomain/public/
    ServerName subdomain.example.biz
</VirtualHost>
```

Lastly, this is my `.htaccess` file if that is helpful:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also: I pinged both domains, and they both point to the same server and I am not using cloudflare, or anything of the like.
I also restarted apache to make sure.

Comment: I can't see example.biz in `ServerName`/`ServerAlias`

Comment: Maybe this answer helps http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217961/26493

Comment: I thought that was probably the issue, but GoDaddy includes the Root domain as an alternate name.

Comment: Can I assume correctly that you have reloaded / restarted the service after making config changes?

Comment: @MattClark In this instance you can correctly assume I restarted it, though in general it is a dangerous assumption!  It is too easy to forget.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I define all of my vhosts in a vhosts file, but in my `httpd.conf` file I apparently set it up with a set of defaults such as:

```
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerNAme example.biz
DocumentRoot /var/www/html   # I wasn't using this folder
```

Once I deleted those erroneous defaults, it started working.